# Dimensionality of tangent vectors in R^2

Tags: normed-spaces, riemannian-geometry, vectors

I am puzzled with the following problem:

given a tangent vector (a d/dx) in the Euclidean plane R^2 with "a" a dimensionless scalar, the dimensionality of this vector is, I suppose, 1/[lenght] and its norm is |a|, a dimensionless scalar.
Now when I take the  vector (x d/dx), it is, I suppose, dimensionless ([lenght]/[lenght]), and its norm is |x|, with dimension of [lenght].

How is it possible to get a norm of a vector dimensionless and not of dimension of [lenght]?

How to unify the treatment of these vectors?

(I could also imagine a vector 1/x d/dx, wich would be of dimension 1/[lenght]^2 and norm 1/[lenght]|)

(The peculiar situation is when we take the vector at point (a,0), lets say, then for both above vector fields, we get the vector (a d/dx) and (a d/dx), but with different dimensionality of both vector and norm.)

Thank you for any help

and wish you a nice afternoon

marfi

Comment: I could also use as example vector fields: -y d/dx + x d/dy and x/Sqrt(x^2+y^2) d/dx + y/Sqrt(x^2+y^2) d/dy.

Comment: Why did you suppose the dimensionality of the vector is different from that of its norm in the first place?